# Does anyone know how a custom SharePoint list to be showed as a persona card?

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-extensions, spfx-tooling, spfx-custom-property-pane

I'm a new in SharePoint solution ,my problem is that i have a custom SharePoint list which have people inside and i want that people with the credentials to be showed as a persona card like MS graph do .Do you have any idea ? Or someone that did the same task ?

Comment: is the list located on the same site as a hub site?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at this sample repository, and see if you can find something that meets your needs?

https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/tree/master/column-samples/person-hover-card

Answer (score 0):

you can SPFx list customizer to customize the OOB fields in SharePoint lists. Here is one example of that https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-extensions/tree/main/samples/js-field-conditionalformatting

Comment: Well my friend i want that sharepoint list to display to the hub site as a card or an image

Comment: can you please elaborate?